# Is it a good idea to style the body tag?

Tags: css, html

In my fixed-width website, I have a layout similar to this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>...</header>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

And my CSS is similar to this:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Styling the `<body>` tag the same way also works, and it makes my code more readable, as I have less nested `<div>` tags.

Is applying margins and a fixed with to the `<body>` a safe idea?

Comment: it's "safe" but fixed-width websites are not a good use of the medium IMO.

Comment: It really depends on what type of styling your talking about. If you're talking a background color then by all means do it to the body. If you're talking setting widths then there are some considerations mentioned below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is perfectly safe, `body` is an HTML element like all the others.

For your layout, you might still want to use `#wrapper` (seems like a fixed width layout), because you might want to set a background for `body` (or do something with the visible "empty" space).

Comment: You can always set a background to the html element itself as well.

Comment: @Madmartigan Thanks, I was not sure that it always works, still researching.

Comment: Would throwing `<html>` into that mix be any less explosive? I'm kinda wondering what *isn't* stylable...

Comment: @Blender: Thank god we can't style the header and the doctype declarations... I hope

Comment: Just found a [nice example](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/195/195.css&page=0) of putting a background image on the HTML tag.

Comment: Whoa. Add this to a stylesheet, and you can see magical stuff: `html, html * { display: block; }`

Comment: @Blender: Dude, that's crazy. Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

I'm testing the width/margin/padding on these elements in IETester now with XHTML Strict doctype.

So far I have the following for `<body>`:

IE 5.5 - FAIL (won't set width, or background expands beyond dimensions), padding/margin OK

IE 6   - PASS

IE 7   - PASS

IE 8  - Honors width but didn't handle padding/margin perfectly

Page I'm using [here](http://wesleymurch.com/test/body.html)

---

Testing with width and margin applied to html element [here](http://wesleymurch.com/test/html.html):

IE 5.5 - SAME, except margin/padding won't work

IE 6   - Will not honor width

IE 7   - Honors width but Will not center with `display:block` and `margin:0 auto` with width set in px.

IE 8  - Honors width but didn't handle padding/margin perfectly

When width was set to the html element in all cases, it actually rendered as if it was padding, by constraining the body element.

This was fun but I'm outta gas with this now, time to get back to actual work ;)

Comment: I doubt many people use IE 5.5, but I didn't know that this stuff happened to IE6/7 with the `<html>` element. I'll have to play around with some crazy CSS and see what I can break...

Comment: Yeah no ones is using IE5.5 of course, but I figured it it ***worked*** in IE 5.5, we'd all feel safe(r) using it.

Answer (score 0):

Styling the body tag is fine but it does mean that should you ever need to make a change on a website you have no other 'spare' tags to modify. The body tag is often a safe tag to leave to facilitate future changes.

To jcomeau_ictx: There are a million reasons to use fixed width websites. I think you'll find more fixed width websites than fluid websites out there.