# Is the body wrapping div really necessary?

Tags: html, css

A popular technique to build a set fixed centered layout is wrap everything in the body in a div and set some CSS rules on it, for example:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        all content here
    </div>
</body>

#wrap { width: 850px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

I was wondering, if there is a reason to add this extra wrapping div, since setting the same CSS rules on the `body` works. Is it for compatibility with some browsers or just a tradition?

Comment: On what browser does it work when setting it on the body?

Comment: @PeeHaa a whole bunch, I've tested it on IE6, IE7, IE8, Chrome 15, Opera 11.60, Firefox 4, Firefox 8

Comment: indeed you seem to be right. Although the margin doesn't work as wyou would expect. I.e. it seem to function more like padding since the background doesn't apply to it and takes the whole width. Didn't knew that though.

Comment: @PeeHaa I'm sure there are some gotcha, in case I get caught by strange behaviour I will try to add that wrapping.

Comment: Have you looked at my fiddle in the comment on [Robs' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721408/is-the-body-wrapping-div-really-necessary#answer-8721493)? I don't think there is a way around that issue. Unless you want to give all (inner) elements a background.

Comment: @PeeHaa saw it now, thanks. Interesting... so it doesn't work as any other div... so wanting to give an inner background would be a case in which the additional wrap is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You do not need a "wrapper" div that so many use because they saw others do so. Use the body for that as you should. Setting CSS properties on the body was a problem in the past but not any longer.

Comment: +1; from experience you're correct but I'd love to see some sources regarding browser support.

Comment: @You - I was trying to find something more authoritative cause I know I read one but this was discussed on SO before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800407/is-it-a-good-idea-to-style-the-body-tag

Comment: Remember that you can go one step further, and turn `body, div#wrap` into `html, body`. That is to say, whatever you would put in `body` goes to `html`, and whatever was in `div#wrap` would go to `body`.

Comment: @BoltClock - True to an extent. There are problems with setting things on the html element but I can't recall what they were.

Comment: @Rob: Mostly `width`/`height` and `padding`/`margin` issues, IIRC. And for the bottom-most element these aren't really relevant properties, anyway.

Comment: [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/styling-the-html-and-body-elements/)'s an (incomplete) article on browser support in styling `html`/`body` elements. And [here](http://camendesign.com/code/developpeurs_sans_frontieres)'s another interesting article on the subject.

Comment: @You - Ah! Yes. Kroc's article, the second one, is the one I remember.

Comment: @Rob you DO still need a wrapper. If you look at the following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NP2ES/) you will see that the entire background is red. So it doesn't use (it does, but different) the margin (what you would expect). Tested in Chrome.

Comment: @PeeHaa - Yes. Read the second article linked to by You.

Answer (score 1):

It might work in some browsers, I don't think it'll work in all of them. Also, it's quite common to set a background on the body, then a separate one on the wrap.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a specific background for the whole page and a centered container, you can't do otherwise. It also provides a way to use "layers" like lightboxes that need to blur the whole `#wrap` content.

Answer (score 0):

To add the extra wrapper enables the body and div to change independently.